# R Finding logistic curve with nls

Tags: r, logistic-regression, panel-data, nls

I have a problem with logistic curve in R for panel data which are here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SO3EzFib7T3XqTz1xZCU2bZFTB0Ddhou/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110784858039906954607&rtpof=true&sd=true

I tried:

```
log <- nls(lrc~SSlogis(time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = data_log)
```

I have an error: 'qr.solve(QR.B, cc)':singular matrix 'a' in solve.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I get a different error:

> Error in nls(y ~ 1/(1 + exp((xmid - x)/scal)), data = xy, start = list(xmid = aux[[1L]],  :
> step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562

(it's not surprising that different platforms will get slightly different results on numerically "difficult" problems ...)

However, here's what `plot(lrc ~ time, data = dd)` produces when I use your data:

[image: plot of lrc vs time - no pattern]

It seems optimistic to think that you could fit a logistic curve to these data, or that the fit would make very much sense ...

I did find that I could fit a logistic to the *logged* data, i.e. `nls(log(lrc) ...)`

```r
plot(log(lrc) ~ time, data =dd)
tvec <- seq(2008, 2016, by = 0.1)
lines(tvec, predict(m2, newdata=data.frame(time=tvec)), col=2, lwd=2)
```

[image: log scale plot + prediction]

If I **really** needed logistic coefficients for this plot (e.g. to compare with other cases) I would fit a linear model to the data, assume that the midpoint was equal to the midpoint of the data, set the scaling parameter equal to the linear slope coefficient divided by 4 (this is a standard rule of thumb for the logistic), and say that the asymptotic value could not be estimated.

---

Plotting all of your data unit-by-unit doesn't make much more hopeful that you will be able to fit logistic curves unit-by-unit either.  While there might be a few units where a logistic curve is a sensible description of the data, it's not in most cases. You might have to back up and consider your analytical strategy — i.e., what are you hoping to learn from these data, and how might you go about it? (If you can frame the question suitably you could post on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). If you are a student/trainee, you might want to ask your supervisor/teacher/mentor for advice ...

[image: panel plot: all units]

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
(dd <- read_excel("data2.xlsx")
  %>% pivot_longer(-code, names_transform = as.numeric,
                   names_to = "year")
  ## indices to break groups into chunks/facets
  %>% mutate(grp_cat = factor(as.numeric(factor(code)) %% 30))
)
gg1 <- ggplot(dd, aes(year, value, group = code,
               colour=code)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grp_cat, scale="free_y") +
  expand_limits(y=0) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.spacing = grid::unit(0, "lines"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
gg1 + geom_smooth(se=FALSE)

ggsave("all.png", width=8, height=8)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer? Maybe better idea is to estimate logistic curve for each unit in my panel data and than take the highest asymptote? I try to estimate logistic curve to obtain horiznontal asymptote. Here are my data with individual units: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Npdo-md5JWFrnmPUZOYUzv3Hcbs6qGnV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110784858039906954607&rtpof=true&sd=true. Can you help me? I'm beginner and I don't know how to estimate logistic curve for 349 units

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive explanation. Maybe I approached to my problem badly. Is it possible to find horizontal asymptote/add logistic trend to my panel data? You wrote that there might be a few units where a logistic curve is a sensible description of the data. How can I find them? How can I use nls and SSlogis across units?

Comment: My question is: how does it make sense to fit a logistic trend to these data, or define a horizontal asymptote, when the data are extremely noisy and don't seem to have a well-defined shape to them in the first place?  Fitting a logistic curve to some of these units *might* be possible, but for most of them it will be more or less meaningless (and give a horizontal asymptote that is extremely uncertain/poorly defined).